# Get fields of MyObject from ArrayList<MyObject>

Tags: java, reflection

I have 2 Classes, `A` and `B`. Class A has some fields, one of them being an `ArrayList<B>`. Now, `B` has some fields of its own(their type&content is not relevant to the problem)

I know how to get the fields of `A`, and display their value, but I have been unable to find a solution that would enable me to also get the fields of `B`, from the `ArrayList<B>` declared in `A`.

Basically, I'm trying to print the content of each `A`, including the content of the `ArrayList<B>`. By content I mean pairs of attributes/fields .

It is assumed I know nothing of `A` and `B` ---> I have to write something very generic. Managed to make it work using reflection until I got to the issue described earlier.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post some code of your own and your own ideas, or you will probably get voted down

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457127/how-to-pull-a-field-from-an-object-stored-in-an-arraylist?rq=1

Comment: Your program's structure worries me. If a class needs to use another object, it should know what methods are available on that object, and if it doesn't it shouldn't be calling any of those methods. Reflection has its purposes, don't get me wrong, but its use always makes me think that there could very well be a better, smarter way of doing things. Perhaps what you're really looking for is to use the [Visitor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_(design_pattern)).

Comment: It is not that i didn't put effort into this, I've been tackling this problem for over a week now. I'm kind'of new to reflection, tried all sorts of thing, this is something that I tried over and over, but still, did not work.

Comment: so far I'm here:
`Object obj=(Object)dataArray.get(0));
for (Field field:(obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) 
{
 field.setAccessible(true); 
        Object value; 
        value = field.get(obj);
 if (value != null) {
      System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
}`

Comment: this gets me all the fields in one instance of A( dataArray is an ArrayList< A >) , and lists me ArrayList< B > as being one of its fields. What I need is to get the fields of all the elements in B. When I list the fields for ArrayList< B > I get lots of fields, and when I look for the variable in the debugger, I can't understand where the values are stored:/ (Note: This program I'm working on is not for practical purposes, it's more of an exercise, for me to learn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
final A a = new A();
for (final Field f : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(f.get(a));
}
```

This loops over all fields in `A` and prints the content. `List` has a nice `toString` method so you just need to have a `toString` method in B and it should work just fine.

If for some reason you cannot do that then recursion would work. This is dangerous however as, unless you know `B` does not have a reference at `A` somewhere, you will end up in an infinite loop.

```
void printMethods(final Object input) {
    for (final Field f : input.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
            final Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) f.get(input);
            for (final Object obj : c) {
                printMethods(obj);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(f.get(input));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple as this:

```
"Bs: " + a.bList();
```

B should override `toString()` too